# Merging JVM and the code into a single file

Tags: java, native-code

I would like to merge Java Virtual Machine and my .java code (or compiled .class files) into a single executable binary. How can I do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2991799/java-to-native-code

Comment: @Raedwald Not really. @user be specific. jvm is not a java file.

Comment: While you can create a .exe file (usually not a good idea) it will use shared libraries so you won't end up with just one file. It is far simpler to specificy that anyone running a JAR has to have Java installed.

Comment: Have in mind that I don't want to compile Java into a machine code - I just want to have everything in a single point-and-click file. Absolutely enough would be having the JVM "glued" with the code somehow, that when I run the file, it runs the JVM and the code

Answer (score 0):

I really doubt you are allowed to do that from the licensing prospective. You are going to let end user use software without passing them through accepting JVM license.

Comment: For many BSD or GPL licensed JVM implementations this would be perfectly ok.  Licensing shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

[GCJ](http://gcc.gnu.org/java/) basically works like that, but depends on the GNU classpath libraries and is not fully compatible with the Java standard (may not support some language features and parts of the standard API).