# Need Help in Running My Java App

Tags: java

I had created a Java Swing Application, I want to run my applications, in all System, Suppose if a System, does not have JRE, then i have to install JRE using Installer in program without aware of the user knowledgeable that the JRE is installed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java to native code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2991799/java-to-native-code)

Comment: @Bombe: no it's not duplicate, i have a doubt  whether going for native will help me or not

Answer (score 2):

There were a few projects for doing this, but from what I can see they all fizzled out - bottom line seems to be that you need a JRE - especially for swing

Comment: Why not just install a JRE on the system?

Comment: My desire is i have to run my exe in all system irrespective of JRE presence

Comment: I can say from experience that deployment issues have always been the thorn in the side of the java client app developer. Since you wish to compile to a windows exe, maybe java (In its current state) is not the best tool for the job? I know it is probably a bit late but would a HTML app / C# suit you better?

Answer (score 2):

The best solution is not to try and install anything silently, but instead to assist the user to install Java.  Oracle's [deployJava.js](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/deployment_advice.html) was designed to do just that, before embedding applets or launching [Java Web Start](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info) applications.

While on the subject of JWS, it is also a good choice for installing/running & updating Java rich client (e.g. Swing) apps. on platforms that support Java.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate an EXE out of your Java source but you will still need the JVM to run it on the destination System. So its not real native.

Comment: if you have a JVM,,, you should also have a JRE, no? I know they are not requisite of each other, but really..

Comment: @apesa: The Java Runtime Environment (JRE) is an implementation of the JVM (Java Virtual Machine).

Answer (score 0):

There is no workaround for running non native class files reliably or really at all without the JRE.