# Which options are there currently for JVM ecosystem AOT compilation

Tags: jvm, native

I'm researching ahead of time compilation of JVM applications, so far I've found GraalVM's Native Image and Kotlin Native, but other than that my searches are coming up rather empty.

I have found JEP295's experimental AOT compiler but is has been removed as of JEP410, which itself refers to GraalVM as an alternative.

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2991799/can-i-compile-java-to-native-code) is pretty outdated, answers mostly suggest discontinued proprietary tech.

Is there anything I'm still overlooking as of 2021

Comment: I think, you already named the options.

Comment: Good to know, I was afraid I was overlooking something cutting edge

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So even Kotlin/Native is practically useles when trying to do anything else than mobile development, so it's only GraalVM at the moment for any one wondering.